# How can I have a constant displacement for a matplotlib marker?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have a fixed offset between the data point of a matplotlib line plot and the referring marker. This means, that independent from the zoom level used, the (green) marker should always be `X` dpi (or cm etc.) below the data point.

I am able to do this by calculating an offset manually when plotting. See example below. But when I zoom into the plot, I get a different offset.

Is there any possibility to tell matplotlib to have a constant displacement between the data point and the marker?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

np.random.seed(0)
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0, 22.0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

randomArray = 0.1 * np.random.rand(50)
randomArray=randomArray.reshape(1,-1)
secondArray = np.array([[2, 2]])
combinedArray = np.c_[randomArray, secondArray]
df = pd.DataFrame(combinedArray.T)
df2 = df-0.2
plt.plot(df, '-', c='r')
plt.plot(df2, 'o', markersize=8, c='g')
plt.show()
```

[image: before zooming]
[image: after zooming]

Comment: Not trivially, but you can tap into the zoom callback and reposition the green dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[matplotlib provides `offset_copy()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/transoffset.html) for this very use-case

```
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

trans_offset = mtransforms.offset_copy(ax.transData, fig=fig,
                                       x=0, y=-0.10, units='inches')

ax.plot(df, '-', c='r')
ax.plot(df, 'o', markersize=8, c='g', transform=trans_offset)
plt.show()
```

[image]